# Browser-Based YouTube Upload in Firefox 16 Aborts Unexpectedly

Tags: firefox, ssl, youtube-api, firefox-16

I have a regular YouTube browser-based upload form, as shown below. It works great in IE, Chrome, and older versions of Firefox. However, my Firefox 16.0.2, just hangs on the POST. I have replicated the problem on other computers with Firefox 16.x.

The file uploads correctly if I manually override the SSL by changing YouTube's URL from: ***https**://uploads.gdata.youtube.com* to ***http**://uploads.gdata.youtube.com*.

To make things even stranger, the request is not logged at all on the *Net* tab in Firebug. On Firefox's *Web Console*, I can see the request, but the response and status code is totally missing. Then, if I use Fiddler with the *Decrypt HTTPS traffic* option enabled the file uploads correctly.

Anyone have any ideas what could be going on or how to monitor the SSL traffic without *fixing* the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>YouTube Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <form id="frmYouTube" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/action/FormDataUpload/YOU_TUBE_URL?nexturl=https%3a%2f%2fMY.DOMAIN.COM%2fDIR_1%2fDIR_2%3fid2%3dLOCAL_ID">
        <table>
            <tr><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="MY_YOUTUBE_TOKEN" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The YouTube url and token are generated on the backend using ASP.Net with the Google.GData.YouTube library. Here is part of that code:

```
public class BaseModel
{

    public string SITE_YOUTUBE_APP_NAME = "";
    public string SITE_YOUTUBE_DEV_KEY = "";
    public string SITE_YOUTUBE_USERNAME = "";
    public string SITE_YOUTUBE_PASSWORD = "";
    public string YOUTUBE_CATEGORY = "";

    public FormUploadToken FormToken;

    public void Load()
    {

        YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(
            SITE_YOUTUBE_APP_NAME, SITE_YOUTUBE_DEV_KEY,
            SITE_YOUTUBE_USERNAME, SITE_YOUTUBE_PASSWORD);

        YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

        Video newVideo = new Video();

        string title = "Test Title";

        string description = "Test Description";

        newVideo.Title = title;
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory(YOUTUBE_CATEGORY, YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
        newVideo.Keywords = "test";
        newVideo.Description = description;
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;

        FormToken = request.CreateFormUploadToken(newVideo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please point us to a page that's running your code so that we could try to reproduce what you're seeing? Also, do you have a Firefox extension installed that automatically munges URLs to convert from HTTP -> HTTPS? I've seen random issues with those sorts of extensions in the past.

Comment: I have tried it on three different computers. I told each person to make sure all their plugins are disabled. Still no dice. It can be tested here: http://54.243.53.37/Home/Index

Comment: I just tried your page with a freshly downloaded Firefox 16.0.2 on OS X 10.8.2 and the uploaded succeeded without issue. I was redirected to http://54.243.53.37/Home/Done?status=200&id=<VIDEO_ID> after the upload.

Comment: Tried it on a OS X 10.8.2 with Firefox 16.0.2 locally, and it failed the first time (in the same way it did before). Tried it twice more and it worked perfectly, which is very odd. I went back and tried it on two other Windows 7 machines with Firefox 16.0.2 and they continue to consistently fail.

Comment: So I just noticed that you are hardcoding the token and upload URL on that test page. I'm trying again to reproduce this and I believe your upload info has expired. Do you have a page where the user is prompted to log in and the token information is filled in dynamically?

Comment: @JeffPosnick The token and url are generated dynamically using the code I've added to my question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming that—I didn't notice that the values were changing each time I reloaded. I just tried a couple of additional times in Windows Firefox 16.0.2 from a couple of different Internet connections, and have not yet had any luck repeating the issue. I've seen some other reports now, though, so I don't doubt that something is up.

Comment: @JakeBraun Did you get any further with this issue?  I'm seeing the same problem on FireFox 24.  Thanks

Comment: @NullReference We added a message for users to upgrade their browser, as Firefox 17 was working for us at the time. Google never got back to me with any other viable solutions for Firefox 16. I'll have to check if Firefox 24 is working for us.

Comment: @JakeBraun Thanks for getting back to me.  I'm using FireFox 24 and still have the same problem.  I'm not sure if the bug is with FF or the YouTubeApi but it would be great to get an official response from Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Firefox 17 is now available and Google does not completely support Firefox 16 for this feature, I added a warning for users with Firefox 16 to upgrade to Firefox 17 or use a different browser. Not ideal, but this was the only reasonable solution given the number of test users who were unsuccessful on Firefox 16.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing YouTube browser based uploading is very temperamental, sometimes it works(1-5% chance) most of the time it doesn't, I just uploaded a video using 54.243.53.37/Home/Index using Firefox 16 on Windows 7, but I know most of the time it just won't initialize.

However disabling your firewall increases the chance of uploading successfully. Not sure why this is though (It could just be lucky observations of course).