# Uploading Browser Based and HTTPS

Tags: youtube-api

First sorry for my bad english!

I need to put an upload form in a facebook application.
I use the browser based upload.

Everything work when i use :

```
$tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
$nextUrl = "https://myurl.com/videoStatut.php";
[...etc...]
```

(but a have a security message)

But when I use

```
$tokenHandlerUrl = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
$nextUrl = "https://myurl.com/videoStatut.php";
[...etc...]
```

The form is sent but my video isn't uploaded and i never see my nexturl.

Thanks for your help.

## PB SOLVED

The update of Firefox (v17) resolved the probleme.
Now https:// call works on all browsers

Comment: Is this the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160214/browser-based-youtube-upload-in-firefox-16-aborts-unexpectedly, i.e. do you only see it in Firefox 16?

Comment: Hello. yes i think is the same problem. I try only on firefox 16.0.2. Have you found where is the problem?

Comment: I tested on IE9 and it's working with https. what can i do for firefox?

Comment: For information an update of Firefox resolve the problem.